# Super thin Arial font in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working on the header of my website and I really like the look of the thin font used in the second part of the title [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/).

I downloaded the source and have been playing around with it. The title used Arial font (although it isn't defined) anywhere and when I integrated the same formatting in my code, the thin part is much thicker.

I have been playing around with the source code a bit and have found that whenever I define a font-family, the thin part gets much thicker.

I want to define it on my site as multiple fonts are used. Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is my code:

```css
.main-title {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #f9f1e9;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.main-title .thin {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-title">Connect <span class="thin">Three</span></h1>
```

Comment: The font in the link provided is 'Raleway', I think that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the web font?

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zn3n2gep/

Comment: Yep, the font was Raleway. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Also you can try Roboto